# ValuError caused by SymLogNorm

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I am trying to generalise a legacy code and had to create a function to plot graphs. The code below is the simplest form I could think of, to present it, while also maintaining replicability.

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def graphs(arr, sub, fig):
   cm=plt.cm.jet
   cm.set_under('white')
   image=sub.imshow(arr,origin='low',cmap=cm,norm=colors.SymLogNorm(linthresh=10))
   sub.axis([-100,100,-100,100])
   divider = make_axes_locatable(sub)
   fig.colorbar(image, cax=divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05))

T=np.random.rand(204,204)*np.nan
T[:T.size//2:2] = 2

fig1, (a1,a2,a3,a4) = plt.subplots(ncols=4,figsize=(15,15))
im1=graphs(T,a1,fig1)
im2=graphs(T,a2,fig1)
im3=graphs(T,a3,fig1)
im4=graphs(T,a4,fig1)
```

`T.npy` is this [file](https://ufile.io/jfqei), containing a `numpy` array with some numbers but mostly `NaN`s. When I remove the `norm` argument the code works (but not the right way, since I need negative values included as well). So I figured that `SymLogNorm` is the culprit. The error I get is:

```
ValueError: Both *x_transform* and *y_transform* must be 2D affine transforms
```

I can't get it to work. My searches of "affine transforms" were not fruitious. Any help is greatly appreciated.

P.S. I tried my best to make it replicable. However, if something is missing, please let me know so I can edit the post.

EDIT: I replaced the file `T.npy` with an array for ease of replicability. The error is the same.

Comment: I can't replicate this. When using some random array, the result looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4efo.png) for me. Maybe you can create some array that replicates the problem within the code (see [mcve]) and also state which matplotlib version you use.

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't work for this array. For random arrays I got it to work as well. However I edited it for an inline array where the error output is the same. `matplotlib: 2.2.2`

Comment: I cannot get the same error, even with matplotlib 2.2.2. However, I also do not get the expected plot either with the updated code. The problem seems to be that there is only a single valid value in the array. Does it work for you if you add another value like `T[2,2] = 5`?

Comment: I get something like [this](https://ibb.co/NSsx4Tq). This seems to fix it. But what about 1 valued arrays?

Comment: Plotting single valued arrays with a logarithmic norm seem to be a bug. You may report it [at the issue tracker](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues).

Comment: OK. Thanks for the input.